# How to access foreign key depends on current active user in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

models.py

```
class Shop(models.model):
   shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
   slug = AutoSlugField()
   logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='restaurant_profile', blank=True)
   related_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    created by = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default="")
```

forms.py

```
class AddProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control input-md',
        'style': 'width: 100%; display: inline;',
    }), required=True)

    price = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control input-md',
        'style': 'width: 100%; display: inline;',
    }), required=True)
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ProductCategory.objects.all(), widget=Select(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control input-md',
        'style': 'width: 100%; display: inline;',
    }), required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product

        fields = [
            'name',
            'price',
            'category',
            'is_published',
            'created_by',
        ]
```

each shop has a related user, when a product is created, created_by field in Product models needs to fill with

```
created_by =  models.ForeignKey(Shop.filter(related_user = request.user)
```

how to assign this value when creating a product from this form 
I am using class-based views

Comment: What is your question? You haven't explained what you're actually trying to achieve and where you got stuck.

Comment: created_by value is the id of shop model where related user = current active user

Comment: How are you creating a product object? are you using django forms?

Comment: yes AddProductForm(forms.ModelForm)

Comment: @VargheseThomas you can do it forms if you're using it or just simply set `request.user` in `views`. Add your relevant code where your product object is being created.

Comment: any examples to perform this in the form model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a form valid method in your views, you can add the logged in user as created by user, example shown is for a class based view

```
   def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = Shop.objects.get(related_user=self.request.user)
        valid_data = super(ProductCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
        return valid_data
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the value of `created_by` in the **form** (not in the view, as you mentioned in the comments), you should pass the `request`, or even better, the `request.user` to the form and add that before saving:

```
class AddProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #...

    fields = [
        'name',
        'price',
        'category',
        'is_published',
        # 'created_by' Remove this
    ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(UserProfileUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().save(commit=False, *args, **kwargs)
        instance.created_by = self.user
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

The final step is to include `user` in views, whenever you instantiate the form:

**views.py**:

```
my_form = AddProductForm(user=request.user)
```